# How to count entries by date with google time stamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a large amount of data from multiple google form submitters with a google timestamp, column A.  I am using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS('Angela-5'!$AQ$2:$AQ,"Missed appointment",INT('Angela-5'!$A$2:$A),TODAY()))
```

to count entries for today, which works.  However, when I try to count entries for the last week,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS('Angela-5'!$AQ$2:$AQ,"Missed appointment",INT('Angela-5'!$A$2:$A),TODAY()-7))
```

it does not work.

How can I make this work?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Answer (score 0):

Try

`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS('Angela-5'!$AQ$2:$AQ,"Missed appointment",INT('Angela-5'!$A$2:$A),(+TODAY()-7)))`

`TODAY()-7` is not being recognised as a formula by the criterion#2; changing it to `(+TODAY()-7)` forces the formula value (a week ago) to be expressed and it is recognised by the criterion#2.

Comment: You should explain what this does and why this solves OP's problem

Comment: (+TODAY()-7) doesn't work either.  Returns a 0, no error message.

Comment: Hmm. It works on my test data. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information), and include an example of a successful outcome. I note that the same request was made yesterday and you haven't yet responded to it.